# Sampling from a pandas dataframe non-repetitively within a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've simplified the code as much as I can but it's still quite long, it should illustrate the problem.

I'm sampling weather data from a dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#dataframe 
dates = pd.date_range('19510101',periods=16000)
data = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,100,(16000,1)), columns =list('A'))
data['date'] = dates
data = data[['date','A']]

#create year and season column
def get_season(row):
    if row['date'].month >= 3 and row['date'].month <= 5:
        return '2'
    elif row['date'].month >= 6 and row['date'].month <= 8:
        return '3'
    elif row['date'].month >= 9 and row['date'].month <= 11:
        return '4'
    else:
        return '1'

data['Season'] = data.apply(get_season, axis=1)
data['Year'] = data['date'].dt.year
```

I want to choose a random year using predetermined year/season tuples:

```
#generate an index of year and season tuples
index =  [(1951L, '1'),
 (1951L, '2'),
 (1952L, '4'),
 (1954L, '3'),
 (1955L, '1'),
 (1955L, '2'),
 (1956L, '3'),
 (1960L, '4'),
 (1961L, '3'),
 (1962L, '2'),
 (1962L, '3'),
 (1979L, '2'),
 (1979L, '3'),
 (1980L, '4'),
 (1983L, '2'),
 (1984L, '2'),
 (1984L, '4'),
 (1985L, '3'),
 (1986L, '1'),
 (1986L, '2'),
 (1986L, '3'),
 (1987L, '4'),
 (1991L, '1'),
 (1992L, '4')]
```

and sample from this in the following way:

generate 4 lists with the years in each season (one list for spring, one for summer etc.)

```
coldsample = [[],[],[],[]] #empty list of lists
for (yr,se) in index: 
    coldsample[int(se)-1] += [yr] #function which gives the years which have extreme seasons [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
coldsample
```

choose a random year from this list

```
cold_ctr = 0 #variable to count from (1 is winter, 2 spring, 3 summer, 4 autumn)
coldseq = [] #blank list
for yrlist in coldsample: 
        ran_yr = np.random.choice(yrlist, 1) #choose a randomly sampled year from previous cell
        cold_ctr += 1 # increment cold_ctr variable by 1
        coldseq += [(ran_yr[0], cold_ctr)] #populate coldseq with a random year and a random season (in order)
```

then generate a new dataframe which chooses multiple random years

```
df = []
for i in range (5): #change the number here to change the number of output years
    for item in coldseq: #item is a tuple with year and season, coldseq is  cold year and season pairs 
        df.append(data.query("Year == %d and Season == '%d'" % item))
```

The problem is that this selects from `coldseq` (which has the same year/season combination) every time, and doesn't generate a new coldseq. I need to reset coldseq to empty and generate a new one for each iteration of the final for loop, but can't see a way of doing this. I've tried embedding code within the loop in multiple ways but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, embedded the loops and reset the counters to 0 within the loop:

```
cold_ctr = 0 #variable to count from (1 is winter, 2 spring, 3 summer, 4 autumn)
coldseq = [] #blank list

df = []
#number of cold years
for i in range (5): #change number here for number of cold years
    for yrlist in coldsample:
        ran_yr = np.random.choice(yrlist, 1) #choose a randomly sampled year from previous cell
        cold_ctr += 1 # increment cold_ctr variable by 1
        coldseq += [(ran_yr[0], cold_ctr)]
    for item in coldseq: #item is a tuple with year and season, coldseq is all extreme cold year and season pairs 
        df.append(data.query("Year == %d and Season == '%d'" % item))
        coldseq = [] #reset coldseq to an empty list so it samples from a new random year
        cold_ctr = 0 #reset counter to 0 so seasons stay as 1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a second dataframe from your index and then sample it.

```
df_index = pd.DataFrame(index)
coldseq = df_index.sample(5)

coldseq.apply(lambda x: df.append("Year == '{0}' and Season == '{1}'".format(x[0], x[1])), axis = 1) # or similar to append the query
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't do what I'm looking for, I want to produce a new dataframe which respects the seasonal sequence (Spring, Summer, Autumn, Winter).

Comment: What's wrong with just ordering the new dataframe after creating it from a random sample?

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't select from a sequence in the way i need it to - I've answered the post with a solution